# f2py compiled fortran kills python kernel when BLAS/LAPACK called

Tags: python, fortran, lapack, blas, f2py

I am trying to run some fortran code with f2py that contains calls to LAPACK and BLAS (see below). It is successfully compiled with the command:

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c test.f -m test2 -LC:\libblas -llibblas -LC:\liblapack -lliblapack
```

I can then use `from test2 import dpbltrf` in python and use the function. However, this kills the kernel when a BLAS/LAPACK function is called within `dpbltrf` with the following message:

```
Kernel died, restarting


 
Restarting kernel... 


 
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: b3d23a22955a11eb8ce69828a61130dc
```

The code I am trying to compile is:

```
      SUBROUTINE DPBLTRF(N, NB, D, LDD, B, LDB, INFO)
      IMPLICIT NONE
! ..Scalar arguments..
      INTEGER N, NB, LDD, LDB, INFO
! ..Array arguments..
      REAL*8 D(LDD,*), B(LDB,*)
! =====================================================================
! .. Local Scalars ..
      INTEGER K

Cf2py intent(in) N
Cf2py intent(in) NB
Cf2py intent(inplace) D
Cf2py intent(in) LDD
Cf2py intent(inplace) B
Cf2py intent(in) LDB
Cf2py intent(out) INFO 


! ..
! .. Executable Statements ..
! ..
!    Test the input arguments.
      INFO = 0
      IF(N .LT. 0) THEN
          INFO = -1
      ELSE IF(NB .LT. 0) THEN
          INFO = -2
      ELSE IF(LDD .LT. NB) THEN
          INFO = -4
      ELSE IF(LDB .LT. NB) THEN
          INFO = -6
      END IF
      IF(INFO .NE. 0) THEN
          RETURN
      END IF
! ..
! Compute Cholesky factorization of the first diagonal block
      CALL DPOTRF('L', NB, D, LDD, INFO)
      IF(INFO .NE. 0) THEN
          RETURN
      END IF
...
...
Additional code but python has already crashed at this point
```

This is from Intel's examples using MKL: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-cookbook/top/factoring-block-tridiagonal-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices.html

It runs as expected when removing this part that contains the call to BLAS:

```
! ..
! Compute Cholesky factorization of the first diagonal block
      CALL DPOTRF('L', NB, D, LDD, INFO)
      IF(INFO .NE. 0) THEN
          RETURN
      END IF
```

I suspect that I have used the wrong LAPACK and BLAS, causing this error. I downloaded precompiled versions from here: `https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries_intel` because I was unable to locate my existing LAPACK/BLAS.

Some additional information that could be usefull:

- Python version 3.8.5 with Anaconda on Windows 10
- Spyder 4.1.5

Is there an obvious reason for why this code kills the kernel in Spyder and what is the correct way to link BLAS/LAPACK functions with my fortran code?

Edit: Running `python3 -m numpy.f2py --help-link lapack_opt_info` indicates that there is no LAPACK installation.

```
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\\Library\\lib']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
Found executable C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\prob_backup\Library\bin\flang.exe
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\\Library\\lib']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
customize AbsoftFCompiler
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize G95FCompiler
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries blas,cblas,lapack not found in ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/prob_backup\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\prob_backup\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\prob_backup\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Edit 2: After installing MKL and the Intel visual fortran compiler 64 bit, I can compile using the following command:

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c --fcompiler=intelvem -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2021.2.0\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win" -lifconsol -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.2.0\lib\intel64" -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.2.0\lib\intel64" -lmkl_sequential -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.2.0\lib\intel64" -lmkl_core -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.2.0\include" test.f -m test1
```

Trying to use the module results in a crash as previously.

Comment: What do you mean by "kills"? If there is an error message can you edit your question to include it, please.

Comment: Not sure at all, but does the command "python3 -m numpy.f2py --help-link lapack_opt_info" possibly give some info?

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of it but I guess there is no LAPACK installation. I also noticed the version I used when compiling was 3.5.0 which is from 2013. I should probably install a more recent version and try again.